# Copy number of file regions to another file?

Tags: python, linux, file, io, seek

I have a potentially large (binary) file, which consists of many small records. Each record has an ID, starts at some **offset** and has a **length**.

Now, I'm interested in only a subset of the records contained in the large file, and I would like to create a new file, that only consists of the records I'm interested in.

I have a list of `(offset, length)` tuples, that specify the location of the records, I am interested in.

I can think of a naive way to do this, e.g.:

```
def copyfragments(src, dst, seekmap):
    for offset, length in sorted(seekmap):
        src.seek(offset)
        dst.write(src.read(length))


bigfile = open('/tmp/large_file.dat', 'rb')
filtered = open('/tmp/filtered.dat', 'wb')

# contains (offset, length) tuples
seekmap = (
    (0, 1021),
    (23020, 1040),
    (35001, 1231),
    ...
)

copyfragments(bigfile, filtered, seekmap)
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this? Can the OS can help more here?

Comment: It's possible memory mapped files (standard library `mmap` module) could be faster / more efficient. Would have to try both ways and measure.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I'll try some benchmarks with mmap and report them here later.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but out of curiosity, is it necessary to do `src.seek(0)`? And pass the `key` to `sorted`? Tuples are sorted by first item by default.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida, thanks for pointing out two really unnecessary things, corrected my question.